Cannot call the backend API in my react code hosted in a frontend VM but can curl the backend API
I have 2 VPCs, one VPC has a frontend VM amd has the react app hosted in it. It has an application load balancer attached to it and I am able to access it properly in my browser. However, the app is calling an API that is hosted on 2 VMs in another VPC which has an internal application load balancer attached to it. I have done the necessary vpc peering. I am able to curl the api in the frontend VMs terminal and get the successful response but the api call within the react app fails with a Connection Timeout
I have tried adding the firewall rules for both the VPCs at port 80. Still face the same issue

Can you add a schema,

What do you mean by a schema ? Sorry new to GCP

Just a diagram of your configuration, your VPCs and so on, just to be clear on what you have!
